# what should i use if i want to run the query for 6 times with parameters changed in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
select b.bookid, b.issuedate, b.returndate
from bookdates b, bookissues e
where exists (select 1 from bookdates where b.bookid = e.book2);
```

I need to execute the above code for 6 times with `book2` replacing with `book1` to `book6`.

Comment: Are you running the query in the MySQL command line tool? Or are you using some programming language to connect to the database and run the query?

Comment: i want to run it on hostinger server.In that the database is mysql.